# How can we remove comma only from new lines in js

Tags: node.js, protractor

I have a string 'str' as given below in my protractor script.I need to replace all 'aaaa' with newline and starting of each new line should not contain comma.

```
var str="51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459aaaa,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541aaaa,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659aaaa";
str=str.replace(/aaaa/g,"\n");
console.log(str);
```

so i will get the result as

```
51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459
,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541
,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659
```

But my aim is to get result as

```
51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459
90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541
01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659
```

So how can i remove comma only from the new lines.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex that will match "aaaa," or "aaaa" and replace that by "\n"

```js
var str="51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459aaaa,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541aaaa,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659aaaa";
str=str.replace(/aaaa,?/g,"\n");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str="51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459aaaa,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541aaaa,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659aaaa";
str=str.replace(/aaaa,?/g,"\n");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But this will not remove last 'aaaa'. Because it is not having comma.I need to replace all 'aaaa' with newline.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using `aaaa,`

Join the array with `\n`

```
var str="51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459aaaa,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541aaaa,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659aaaa";

str = str.split('aaaa,').join('\n');

console.log(str);
```

EDIT: It looks like the last aaaa was not removed using the code above..
UPDATE:

Split the string using `aaaa`
Map the array to remove first character
Join the array back using `\n`

```
var str="51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459aaaa,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541aaaa,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659aaaa";

str = str.split('aaaa').map(s => s.slice(1)).join('\n');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459aaaa,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541aaaa,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659aaaa";

str = str.toString().replace(/aaaa,/g, '\n');

console.log(str);
```

make sure to add .toString() first before .replace()